# Update table em formato errado

Tags: php, mysql

```
update table set pontuacao='$var1' where id='1' AND diadojogo > '2017-09-28';
update table set pontuacao='$var1' where id='1' AND diadojogo >  2017-09-28 ;
update table set pontuacao='$var1' where id='1' AND diadojogo > '$data';
```

Sei que está errado esta sintaxe! Quero salvar a `var1` no field `pontuacao` do `id=$x` somente se a `$data` for menos que o que consta em `diadojogo`, que é uma *varchar* formato `'2017-09-28'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update palpite set pontuacao='4' where (id='1' and diadojogo > '2017-09-26');
```

Comment: Essa é a resposta da sua pergunta?

Comment: Sim! Essa é a resposta da minha pergunta!

Comment: Ele que ela ta bem parecida com o da pergunta, cuidado para não levar negativo desnecessário, dá uma explicada! é só uma dica!

Comment: Está parecido, mas a resposta está correta. Acha necessário excluir?

Comment: Não, acho que não, só foi um alerta mesmo ...

Comment: Excluir não, mas explicar qual a diferença da resposta para a expressão da pergunta e explicar porquê uma funciona e a outra não. Isso irá aumentar a qualidade da resposta.